# Mixing in Less CSS

Tags: css, less, lesscss-resources

I'm still new at using Less CSS and I couldn't find a solution to my problem.
I want a more efficient output result.

I have this code in less :

```
.btn-trans {
      color: inherit;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all .4s;

      &.btn-default {
        color: @trans-default;
        &:hover {
          color: @trans-hover-color;
        }
      }

      &.btn-primary {
        color: @trans-primary;
        &:hover {
          color: @trans-hover-color;
        }
     }
  }
```

And this is the css output :

```
.btn-trans {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.btn-trans.btn-default {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.btn-trans.btn-default:hover {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.btn-trans.btn-primary {
  color: #738ffe;
}

.btn-trans.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

But the result I'm looking for is this :

```
.btn-trans {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.btn-trans.btn-default {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.btn-trans.btn-primary {
  color: #738ffe;
}

.btn-trans.btn-default:hover,
.btn-trans.btn-primary:hover {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

With the hover classes nested since the color is the same.

Comment: I've succeeded getting the desired result by adding `&.btn-default, .btn-primary {&:hover {color: @trans-hover-color;}}`, if there's a better way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a class that is pretty much like grouping the selectors you want to use together.

**Snipet**

```
.custom-class(){
  .btn-trans.btn-default:hover,
    .btn-trans.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    }
}/*-- end of the custom class --*/
.btn-trans {
      color: inherit;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all .4s;

      &.btn-default {
        color: #ccc;

        &:hover {
          color: #ccc;
        }
      }

      &.btn-primary {
        color: #ccc;

        &:hover {
          color: #ccc;
        }
     }
  }

/*-- use of the custom class --*/
.custom-class;
```

or you can go for a nested approach by grouping on the upper level

**snipet**

```
.btn-trans {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .4s;

  &.btn-default {
    color: #ccc;
  }

  &.btn-primary {
    color: #ccc;
  }

  &.btn-default,
  &.btn-primary {
    &:hover {
      color: #ccc;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The generate CSS is perfectly OK except that it costs two more lines in file size.

If you really want your output, you can try this:

```
.btn-trans {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: all .4s;

  &.btn-default {
    color: @trans-default;
  }

  &.btn-primary {
    color: @trans-primary;
  }

  &.btn-default,
  &.btn-primary {
    &:hover {
      color: @trans-hover-color;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    .btn-trans {
      color: inherit;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all .4s;
      &.btn-default {
        color: @color;
       }
     &.btn-primary {
       color: @color;
      }

     &.btn-default,
       &.btn-primary {
       &:hover {
       color: @color;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: How is this different from the second snippet in the accepted answer (other than the #ccc to @color change which you made just now)?

Comment: Oh sorry i did not saw the above answer. I am taking my answer back. going to delete it.